# Why can I use the class member variables in static Main Function?

Tags: c#

As I know, static function doesn't allow any static variables in C#, right?
`Main()` function is **static function**, but I have been using my own class.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public int size = 300;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();

            // this is error
            size = 500;

            // why this is not error, despite Test Class's object's member length is not a static member?
            // i think that Main is static if so length variable shouldn't it be static ?
            t.length = 300;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
       public int length;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Use only the language tag that the code is actually written in.

Comment: Also from a static method, you *can* access non-static fields of a class, if you have an instance of this class available. Here you have the instance `t` that you created with `new Test()`.

Comment: `t.length = 300;` there is no `error` in this because you are accessing it with `t` but `size` you can't access like this you have to use `(new program()).size=100;` basically an `object` of Program class.

Comment: thank you  all . *^^*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non-static classes (normal class)

When you have a class, you must create it (instanciated it), then you can access it properties. Eg:

```
class Car
{
    public int Wheels = 4;
}

Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Wheels = 8;
Console.WriteLine(myCar.Wheels); //output: 8
```

Also note, when you try to access it like a `static` property of the class `Car`, it won't work:

```
class Car
{
    public int Wheels = 4;
}

Car.Wheels = 8; //ERROR
```

---

### Static classes

Difference compared to the static classes/static methods is that, You are accessing something that is only **once** there (it is static!):

```
static class MyStaticClass
{
    //public int y = 3;  //ERROR: this is invalid, static class can't have instance variables

    public static int x = 5;  //variable must be also static
}

//You don't have to instantiate (create `new MyStaticClass()`) anymore.
MyStaticClass.x = 3;
Console.WriteLine(MyStaticClass.x = 3);
```

---

### Combination (your example)

Each class (either static or non-static) can have a **static methods/variables**. Both below are valid:

```
class FirstClass
{
    public static int x = 5;
    public static void Test() { }
}

static class SecondClass
{
    public static int x = 5;
    public static void Test() { }
}
```

But the difference is when You wan't to work with them:

```
//Working with non-static class, is an instance, can create multiple instances
FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
FirstClass fc2 = new FirstClass();
FirstClass fc3 = new FirstClass();
fc.x = 3;
Console.WriteLine(fc.x);
fc.Test();

//Static class has only single instance, created on program start - it is "static"
SecondClass.x = 3;
Console.WriteLine(SecondClass.x);
SecondClass.Test();
```

---

Method `static void Main()` is *static* , which means it can only access other static properties/methods. To access "non-static" properties/methods you need a reference to a created instance, like `new Program()`:

```
class Program
{
    public int size = 300;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        size = 123; //Error, because it doesn't know to which instance it goes
        Program.size = 123; //Error, because Program is non-static class
        
        //It must first have some instance of Program to work with.
        Program p1 = new Program();
        Program p2 = new Program();
        p1.size = 123;
        p2.size = 234;
        Console.WriteLine(p1.size == p2.size); //compare, not same, 2 different properties
    }
}
```

Comment: In `fc.x = 3;` and `fc.Test();` you are using the fields/methods like they are instance fields/methods. However, they are `static` and should be accessed like that to avoid confusions. The IDEs will usually give you a warning about such an access. Either change them to `static` access or change the example class `FirstClass` to use non-static fields/methods. However, this might change the meaning of the example you are trying to say.

Comment: @Progman I understand the reasoning behind, my explanation might be poor, don't hesitate to edit it for better clearing/explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable gets initialized only once during the life cycle of a class whereas a non-static variable gets initialized either 0 or n number of times, depending on the number of objects created for that class.

**Rules to follow while working with static and non-static members in c#:**

1. Non-static to static: Can be consumed only by using the object of that class.
2. Static to static: Can be consumed directly or by using the class name.
3. Static to non-static: Can be consumed directly or by using the class name.
4. Non-static to non-static: Can be consumed directly or by using the “this” keyword.

Refer to this [link](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/static-and-non-static-members-csharp/) for a clear understanding of Static and non-static members in C#.

Comment: welcome @Theremin if it is helpful then you can accept one of the answers as an accepted answer. This is how it works in Stackoverflow :)